# Apache2 compile wsgi for python 3.4

Tags: python, apache2, wsgi

I'm trying to get a django application working with apache2, given that the application runs in a conda environment with python 3.4. Since I got "django not found" errors and that I installed first wsgi with `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`, I then compiled a version of wsgi with python3.4 doing the following:

```
make distclean
LD_RUN_PATH=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib ./configure --with-python=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python
make
sudo make install
```

Then I checked in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules` and saw these two files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 950232 févr.  1 11:28 mod_wsgi-py34.cpython-34m.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 948480 févr.  1 11:36 mod_wsgi.so
```

Finally I created a file `wsgi.load` in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/` with the following content:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

But I still get this error. I don't know what to try anymore to get this django app running:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython
```